# How to copy Nuget Package Dependencies

Tags: c#, nuget

We are currently refactoring an old win forms app which uses a framework as referenced project across the whole application. I am fairly new to nuget and .net so I hope you don't mind my newbiew question.

We created a nuget package from the csproj (Syncing.nupgk). That package references other packages like Newtonsoft or Consul. When I build the project, my syncing.dll gets copied to the bin folder of the win forms project, but other dlls (newtonsoft.dll, consul.dll) are copied outside in a packages folder with a structure lib\net45 etc.

How I can tell visual studio that I also need the newtonsoft.dll in the bin folder of the project as it is a dependencie of my syncing.dll

thx!

Comment: That's how NuGet works, by pulling packages into a packages folder. Have you tried building your project? I would expect to see the DLLs show up in your bin folder at that point.

Comment: The project builds fine, its just that it throws a System.IO.FileNotFoundException because it can´t find the  consul and newtonsoft dlls which are not in the bin folder. Its a dotnet framework 4.6.1 class library.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `nuspec` file for this purpose. In your case, you would have `Syncing.csproj.nuspec` which looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Syncing</id>
    <authors></authors>
    <owners></owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <licenseUrl></licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl></projectUrl>
    <iconUrl></iconUrl>
    <description></description>
    <language></language>
    <tags></tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
        <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        ...
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

You can look at these two links for more info:
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec
- This is how I'm using .nuspec file to publish the instrumentation library on https://github.com/borkke/opentracing-csharp-mongo/blob/master/src/OpenTracing.Contrib.Mongo/OpenTracing.Contrib.Mongo.csproj.nuspecnuget